# Python How to Canel a Function when an event is called(Turtle Graphics)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

In the following function:

```
def back():
    global turncount
    stdraw.clear()
    eraseData()
    turncount -= 1
    newState(gameData[turncount])
    gamePiece()
    buttoncolor()
    time.sleep(2)
    whosTurnnow()
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to stop a function from executing if an event is called on turtle graphics.

For example, suppose a user clicks on turtle graphics screen, this line will execute `wn.onclick(back)`.

Now suppose that when the function back is executed after clicking on the turtle graphic window and it is now executing the line `time.sleep(2)` which waits 2 seconds before executing the next line(`whosTurnnow()`).

Now during this time suppose a user clicks again on the turtle graphic screen, the function `back()` will be called again.

The question is, is there a way to cancel the previous call on the first time and ignore the last line after `time.sleep(2)`, which is `whosTurnnow()`, and run that line on the second call only.

Comment: no easy, elegant one

Comment: Do you mean the question was not clear?

Comment: no. I mean that there is no elegant solution. See my answer ;-).

Answer (score 0):

One (non-elegant, very bad) solution would be:

```
running = 0
def myBack(): never overrive functions (here: turtle.back)
    global running
    imthenext = False
    if running>0: imthenext = True
    running += 1
    todo = """global turncount
stdraw.clear()
eraseData()
turncount -= 1
newState(gameData[turncount])
gamePiece()
buttoncolor()
time.sleep(2)
whosTurnnow()""".split("\n")
    for line in todo:
        if running>1 and not imthenext: running-=1; return
        else: exec(line, globals(), locals())
```

But it should work (not tested)...

If there is *any* other solution, take it and forget this one. This is only working. Not good.

You'll have to call this function with ontimer (-> thread).

P.S.: Never forget that you *cannot* do *anything* while time.sleep is executed.

Comment: This is very bad code style but the only solution I see :(.